# Angular 4 Directives in ionic framework

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have some calculation function which is used in many pages.I want to create a common function instead of more than one function in ionic framework.I do research on directives and link function but don't get appropriate example.If anyone have a proper example about it then pass me the link.

Answer (score 0):

try using and creating service. for an example create a service file.

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


    @Injectable()

    export class CommonService {
      commonFunction(list: any[], obj: any, key: string): number {
    // Your logic here.
//return your logic varibale
      }
    }
```

and then you can inject this service into any Component, which is easy and useful.

```
import {CommonService} from 'app/shared';

export MyComponent {

  constructor(private CS: CommonService) {
    CS.commonFUnction([], {}, 'id'); // just an example usage
  }
}
```